# Where clause with a conditional condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

**Case:** I have a stored procedure in where I got all the information of a table.
I have 2 parameters in order to set the Where clause but one of those could be
0.

**Question:** How do I do a `Case When` or an `If` in my `Where` clause depending on my parameter value? 
I want to apply the where clause only if the value is different from 0 
if is 0 I don't want to do it.

**Code:**

```
@ID_ORDER,
@ID_SUPPLIER 

Select *
From Orders ord
where @ID_SUPPLIER = ord.ID_SUPPLIER
AND CASE WHEN @ID_ORDER = 0 THEN ord.ID_ORDER = @ID_ORDER END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.  You just use `and` and `or`:

```
select *
from Orders ord
where ord.ID_SUPPLIER = @ID_SUPPLIER) and
      (ord.ID_ORDER = @ID_ORDER or @ID_ORDER = 0);
```

Note that the logic you are attempting is backwards.  This only applies the filter on `id_order` when the value is not `0`.

Comment: That's right I wrote it wrong I put "=" instead of "!=".
Anyways this solved my problem thank you!